# webpack/babel/react - unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm already using `babel-preset-react` and `babel-preset-es2015`.

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "react-spring-demo",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "webpack.config.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "webpack": "^1.13.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.1.0"
      }
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: [
      './app/app.js'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, include: __dirname + '/app', loader: "babel", query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] } }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "react"] }
```

I think I'm missing something very simple. I've already tried a few things like using `./app` instead of `__dirname + "/app"` and using `.js$` instead of `.jsx?$`. Also, you'll notice I'm using the latest versions of all the dependencies. I've read numerous other posts about people having problems when updating to babel 6 because of a missing react preset. This seems to be something different. Shouldn't these versions not have issues? Thanks

Comment: we are using this: test: /\.js$/ any good?

Comment: I tried that too. No luck :/

Comment: Need a better error report please.

Comment: I included a better error report in my answer!

Answer (score 3):

@Richard

```
ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\vdixit\Desktop\react-spring-demo\src\main\resources\static\app\app.js Unexpected token (6:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Alright, I found a fix. Apparently using the npm `path` module fixes this.

Instead of:

```
include: __dirname + '/app'
```

I used:

```
  include: path.join(__dirname, '/app'),
```

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using windows for anyone else with this issue- but I read somewhere that this fix also works for mac